# Morritte of the Frost copying Dark Depths

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Moritte of the Frost](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Moritte%20of%20the%20Frost) may enter the battlefield as a copy of a permanent you control.  [Dark Depths](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dark%20Depths) enters the battlefield with 10 ice counters on it.  If I have Moritte enter as a copy of my Dark Depths, does it have 10 ice counters on it?

Comment: Dark Depths is legendary though,

Comment: @NeilMeyer the combos that use it don't care, the point is to cheat out Marit Lage as fast as you can by either removing all the counters at once ([Vampire Hexmage](https://scryfall.com/card/2xm/112/vampire-hexmage)) or having never had them there in the first place ([Solemnity](https://scryfall.com/card/hou/22/solemnity) or [Thespian's Stage](https://scryfall.com/card/2xm/327/thespians-stage)) Having to sacrifice the original due to legend rule in the versions of the combo that copy the card doesn't bother the deck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. By copying Dark Depths, it acquires the ability "Dark Depths enters the battlefield with ten ice counters on it.", and thus gets the ice counters.

(In contrast, [Thespian's Stage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Thespian%27s%20Stage) works as a combo with Dark Depths because it can turn into a copy *after* it has entered the battlefield, and thus without getting the ice counters.)

> 707.5. [...] If the text that's being copied includes any abilities that replace the enters-the-battlefield event (such as "enters the battlefield with" or "as [this] enters the battlefield" abilities), those abilities will take effect. [...]